# no math is generated when using tikz/forest with tex4ht in mathjax mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, forest

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode 
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20,
    minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2cm,
    align=center, base=b,
    s sep=1cm, l sep=.5cm,
    if level<=2{edge=-latex}{edge=red},
}
[differential\\equation
    [\begin{minipage}{2cm}     
     first order
     \vspace{-8pt}
     {\begin{align*} 
       f(x,y,(y')^n)&=0
     \end{align*} 
     }
     \end{minipage}
     ,calign=last
   ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

When compiled using

```
make4ht  -ulm default -a debug foo4.tex "htm" "-cunihtf -utf8"
```

Gives this HTML

[image]

But when compiling using mathjax mode

```
 make4ht  -ulm default -a debug foo4.tex "mathjax,htm" "-cunihtf -utf8"
```

Gives this html

[image]

The math is missing.

I tried with and without `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}` as I was not sure if this is needed for mathjax, but it made no difference. Same result was generated. Math is missing in mathjax mode.

Does this mean one should compile the Tikz/Forest diagram to standalone image and include that as an image in HTML instead of doing it all inline as in the above example?

TL 2022

```
which tex4ht 
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tex4ht
make4ht --version 
make4ht version v0.3l
```

Comment: If I see that correct, your MathJax routine creates a svg graphic and even the text is transformed to a (vector) image. Just a guess but since `forest` first typesets stuff to measure it before it actually is put on the page I could see this somehow causing trouble in the transformation.

Comment: (Off-Topic: Instead of a `minipage` you could just use `text width=2cm` which for LaTeX even does the same.)

Comment: **Instead of a minipage you could just use text width=2cm** I must be doing something wrong, but now it does not compile. Here is what I tried `\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20,
    minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2cm,
    align=center, base=b,
    s sep=1cm, l sep=.5cm,
    if level<=2{edge=-latex}{edge=red},
}
[differential\\equation
    [text width=2cm, 
     first order   
     {\begin{align*} 
       f(x,y,(y')^n)&=0
     \end{align*} 
     }    
     ,calign=last
   ]
]
\end{forest}` I am new using forest.

Comment: I thought I needed `minipage` since this will be paragraph with math in it and it is easier to make it its own page.

Comment: The first part (up to a `,`) after `[` is always the content: `[{\begin{align*}…\end{align*}}, text width=2cm, first order, calign=last]` (This node will be wider than 2cm because it will add the `inner xsep` to both sides.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is quite complicated. Most math environments are redefined in the MathJax mode in the way that they cannot be used in pictures. Other than externalization, the only way I can think of is to redefine environments back to their original meaning at the beginning of the forest environment. The example for the `align*` environment can look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/forest/begin}{%
  \renewenvironment{align*}
  {\start@align \@ne \st@rredtrue \m@ne}
  {\math@cr \black@ \totwidth@ \egroup \ifingather@ \restorealignstate@ \egroup \nonumber \ifnum 0=`{\fi \iffalse }\fi \else $$\fi \ignorespacesafterend}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\AddToHook{env/forest/begin}` executes code at the begiinig of the forest environment. The change is local, so the `align*` environment will still work with MathJax outside of `forest`.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: hello Michal. I found  a big problem. But since it is now using tikzpicture and not forest,. I thought it will be better to post separate question so not to clutter this one?

Comment: fyi, I've posted separate question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666705/no-math-is-generated-when-using-tikz-tikzpicture-with-tex4ht-in-mathjax-mode